# fibre-preserving homotopy equivalence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

Let $p:E\to B$ and $p':E'\to B$ be fibrations. It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber-homotopy_equivalence) that if $f:E\to E'$ a fibrewise map that is also a homotopy equivalence, then it is a fibrewise homotopy equivalence.

What about the more general situation of fibrations $p:E\to B$ and $p':E'\to B'$ over different bases? A *fibre-preserving map* from $p$ to $p'$ is a pair of maps $f:E\to E'$ and $\overline{f}:B\to B'$ such that $\overline{f}\circ p=p'\circ f$, and a *fibre-preserving homotopy* between such maps is a pair of homotopies $H:E\times I\to E'$ and $\overline{H}:B\times I\to B'$ such that the following diagram commutes:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
  E\times I @> H >> E'\\
    @V p\times\operatorname{Id} V V @VVp'V\\
   B\times I @> \overline{H}>> B' 
\end{CD}

One can then easily define a *fibre-preserving homotopy equivalence* from $p$ to $p'$.

> Question: Is there an example of a fibre-preserving map of fibrations
> \begin{CD}
>   E @> f >> E'\\
>     @V p V V @VVp'V\\
>    B @> \overline{f}>> B' 
> \end{CD}
> such that $f$ and $\overline{f}$ are homotopy equivalences, but the pair $(f,\overline{f})$ is not a fibre-preserving homotopy equivalence, i.e. does not admit a fibre-preserving homotopy inverse?

Comment: I don't think so. Doesn't the proof of the Proposition on p. 47 of Peter May's [book](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf) dualize?

Comment: @GustavoGranja It would appear that Peter May thinks so: see p. 53 of the same book! I'll try to check the details and get back to you. Barring a major surprise, this reference seems to be a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @GustavoGranja well I didn't check all details, but enough to have faith that it's true. If you'd like to post this reference as an answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: This also follows from formality: Give $\mathsf{Top}$ with the Hurewicz model structure. The arrow category $\operatorname{Arr}(\mathsf{Top})$ admits the injective model structure. In this model structure, every object is cofibrant; fibrant objects are precisely the fibrations in $\mathsf{Top}$. If $f$ and $\overline{f}$ are homotopy equivalences, then $(f,\overline{f})$ is a weak equivalence in $\operatorname{Arr}(\mathsf{Top})$ between fibrant-cofibrant objects, and hence is a homotopy equivalence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question as asked is no: a fibre-preserving map of fibrations in which the maps of total and base spaces are homotopy equivalences is neccessarily a fibre-preserving homotopy equivalence (also known as a *homotopy equivalence of fibrations*). A reference was supplied in the comments by Gustavo Granja, to Peter May's book *A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology*, where the statement appears as a Proposition on page 53. (The proof, although not given in detail, does appear to be a straightforward dualization of the corresponding result for cofibrations, proved on page 48.)